# How to separate parallel requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I'll try to explain the issue with a simplified console application example, however the real project is a ASP.NET MVC3 application.

Having the following tables:

[image]

imagine the following scenario:

1. user creates a report (a line in `TestReport`, where `Text` is the report `string` content, and `Ready` is a `bool` flag, saying, if the report is ready to be processed); by default `Ready` is set to `false`, i.e. not ready.
2. user wants the report to be processed, so he submits it; `Ready` is set to `true` here.

The system gives an opportunity to recall the report back, if it has not been processed yet. So, when the report is recalled, `Ready` is set to `false` back. On the contrary, when the report is processed, a line in `TestReportRef`, referencing report by its `Id`, is created.

Now imagine that at one and the same moment

1. user wants to recall the report;
2. the report is added to the process list;

As soon as this can happen simultaneously, errors may occur. That is the report will have `Ready` == `false` and it'll be referenced in `TestReportRef`.

Here is a simple console example of how this may happen:

```
var dc = new TestDataContext('my connection string');
dc.TestReport.InsertOnSubmit(new TestReport
{
    Text = "My report content",
    Ready = true //ready at once
});
dc.SubmitChanges();

Action recallReport = () =>
{
    var _dc = new TestDataContext(cs);
    var report = _dc.TestReport.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ready);
    if (report != null && !report.TestReportRef.Any())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        report.Ready = false;
        _dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
};

Action acceptReport = () =>
{
    var _dc = new TestDataContext(cs);
    var report = _dc.TestReport.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Ready);
    if (report != null && !report.TestReportRef.Any())
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        _dc.TestReportRef.InsertOnSubmit(new TestReportRef
        {
            FK_ReportId = report.Id
        });
        _dc.SubmitChanges();
    }
};

var task1 = new Task(recallReport);
var task2 = new Task(acceptReport);

task1.Start();
task2.Start();

task1.Wait();
task2.Wait();

foreach (var t in dc.TestReport)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", t.Id, t.Text, t.Ready));
}

foreach (var t in dc.TestReportRef)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ref id:\t" + t.FK_ReportId);
}
```

`Thread.Sleep(1000);` is added to be ensure, that tasks will check one and the same situation.

The given example may sound awkward, however, I hope, it should explain the issue I'm dealing with.

How can I avoid this? Making the repository singleton doesn't seem to be a good idea. **Shall I use some shared mutex (one for all web requests) to separate write-operations only?**
Or is there a pattern I should use in this kind of scenario?

---

This is only a simplified example of one of the scenarios I have. However, there are several scenarios in which it may run into a similar discrepancy. The best thing would be to make this kind of intersection impossible, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't add a `version` column on the Report table? Task starts by tracking current version,when task end, if the version is the same that the tracked one, operation is ok, otherwise fail. If operation appear ok, update the version to version +1. This is a sort of optimistic lock; that implicitly suppose that conflicts may occur, but they are not so frequent.

**UPDATE**

If you are using linqto sql maybe you can have a check at the parameter [UpdateCheck](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.updatecheck.aspx) `[Column(UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Always)]`
This can be useful to handle concurrency in your case.

Comment: This approach would result in adding `version` column to almost every table. And in the real project the task needs to check different tables (several rows in each). Keeping locks for all the lines involved seems to be quite a complicated task. Besides it would require to write rollback operations for each situation, when the result may be not OK. Of course, I would love to avoid all these things.

Comment: an optimistic approach can be used also by checking all field are still the same as you read before you write. Are you using any OR/M?

Comment: This does not change anything. As soon as I edit rows from different tables, no problem can be revealed there by LinqToSql. While at the moment when the original values are checked they are all unchanged yet.